# c# Build Error with LINQ syntax in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi folks I have the following error on line 11 in this controller code :

```
    public JsonResult GetChartData_IncidentsBySiteStatus(string SiteTypeId, string searchTextSite, string StartDate, string EndDate)
    {
        if (searchTextSite == null)
            searchTextSite = "";

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(EndDate);

        var sitesQry = _db.Sites;
        if (SiteTypeId != "-1")
            sitesQry = sitesQry.Where(a => a.SiteTypeId.ToString() == SiteTypeId);

        var qry = from i in _db.Incidents   
                  join s in _db.Sites on i.SiteId equals s.SiteId
                  where s.SiteDescription.Contains(searchTextSite)
                    && (i.Entered >= startDate && i.Entered <= endDate)
                  group s by s.SiteStatus.SiteStatusDescription + "[" + s.SiteTypeId.ToString() + "]"
                      into grp
                      select new
                      {
                          Site = grp.Key,
                          Count = grp.Count()
                      };

        return Json(qry.ToList()  , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

...........the error is:

> Error 7   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\IRenewables_EMAS\IRenewables_EMAS\Controllers\IncidentController.cs    69  28  Emas.Web

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

thanks

Comment: Which line exactly is line 11? The casting is incorrect, and that particular `IQueryable` object is not providing an `Table` interface.

Comment: Line 11: sitesQry = sitesQry.Where(a => a.SiteTypeId.ToString() == SiteTypeId);

Comment: why not get rid of that line and in your query go : where (s.SiteId.Equals(SiteTypeId) && !s.SiteId.Equals("-1") ...

Comment: Alternatively you could potentially go var sitesQry = _db.Sites.AsQueryable(); ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a [base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) instance to a [sub class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) instance.

Instead of

```
var sitesQry = _db.Sites;
```

try using

```
IQueryable<Site> sitesQry = _db.Sites;
```

Comment: While you suggestion is correct, I feel as though your explanation is not. `IQueryable` is not a base class, its an interface. This means that, while the `Table` class may implement the interface, calling it a base/sub class relationship is fundamentally incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

While @Eranga 's solution may work, I feel as though there are more options and a better explanation available.

Firstly, the reason that you cannot assign the value is because you are trying to assign and implementation of an interface to a concrete type. THis cannot be done because you have no idea what could be implementing that interface, and this means that the it cannot be assigned to something that has a concrete type.

There are multiple options for this. You can do as @Eranga suggests and create a new variable

```
IQueryable<Site> sitesQry = _db.Sites;
```

or you can call the .[`CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method that is exposed by Linq.

```
sitesQry = _db.Sites.CopyToDataTable();
```